# getting error of cookies disabled error in vaadin 14 in IOS

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am getting the following error in vaadin 14

```
Cookies disabled 

This Application requires Cookies to function

please enable cookies in your browser and click here or Esc to try again
```

I am using spring boot with vaadin 14 and also microservices.

Any type of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but do you have cookies disabled?

Comment: Yes its disabled..!! And this error is showing like in red in ui as a pop up..!! So is there any way we can get rid of this as currently i am unable to proceed like any operations in my application due to this.

Comment: You need to enable cookies to use a Vaadin application.

Comment: Its happening as we have registered our vaadin application in shopify platform and there we are showing our application in an i frame..!! this error is reported only in safari browser.If we run vaadin app independently then there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are needed for Vaadin, so it can keep the same `Session` over multiple `Requests`. When you use Vaadin, you are *required* to enable cookies in your browser as user of the application. If your users are reporting this, tell them to *enable cookies in their browser*.

Disabling all cookies in browser is a bad practice, and doesn't make much sense in this day and age. I can understand wanting to disable some tracking cookies, but this can be done without disabling all cookies altogether.

**Cookies aren't a bad thing!** Make this clear to your users that report this.

Comment: Hi @Kscherrer Actually we came to know like our vaadin Application is being loaded in an iframe in shopify and the cookies are enabled already but in safari in ios they aren't allowing this behavior so its being hard to achieve that only in safari like its the problem.I frame that is being loaded in the shopify website and safari isn't allowing i frame to load from other websites.

Comment: so can you give like a solution to load anything in an i frame in safari from other websites and make that run I know I posted this question for vaadin but its a type of generic thing now

Comment: I don't have a solution to that. Please add this information into the question, or even create a new question for that, because it's something completely different than what you asked initially